# How to convert void * to int without losing information (in c)?

Tags: c, type-conversion

If void* holds a variable amount of information, isn't possible that simply storing it in an integer would loose information? Shouldn't the information be stored in several integers (aka int*)?

ex:

```
int func(void* info){
int num = (int)info;
return num;
}
```

if info = Absdfsdfskewlrew.... , wouldn't num not be able to correctly hold this information?

Comment: Yes.  You can't store more than 32 bits' worth of information in a 32-bit int.  But why are you asking?  Why are you trying to "convert `void *` to `int`"?  And are you trying to convert the pointer, or the data that it points to?

Comment: You are type-casting the address stored in `info` to an int rather than the data stored in that address.  The correct data-type for casting the address stored in a `void *` into a signed integral type, however, is `intptr_t`.

Comment: Did someone tell you that `void *` was a "generic" type in C?  That could "hold" any type of data?  That's not quite true.  `void *` is a generic *pointer* type, that can *point to* any type of data.

Answer (score 1):

1. Passing the pointer tho the int variable

```
int func(void* info)
{
   // not very good. Pointer punning should be avoided
   int num = *(int *)info;

   // or better
   memcpy(&num, info, sizeof(num));

   /* other code */

   return num;
}


//And usage

int x = 6;
func(&x);
```

Answer (score 1):

`void*` is sometimes used to pass a pointer to a value of "any type" to a function.

You will also need another parameter to describe what the void* actually points to, so that you can cast it to the correct pointer type.

The following example illustrates the concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    what_int,
    what_float,
    what_string
} what_t;

void print_it(what_t what, void *value)
{
    switch (what) {
        case what_int:
            printf("It is an int: %d\n", * (int*) value);
            break;
        case what_float:
            printf("It is a float: %f\n", * (float*) value);
            break;
        case what_string:
            printf("It is a string: %s\n", (char*) value);
            break;
        default:
            printf("I don't understand what it is\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    print_it(what_int, &i);

    float f = 3.1415;
    print_it(what_float, &f);

    char *s = "Hello world";
    print_it(what_string, s);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
It is an int: 5
It is a float: 3.141500
It is a string: Hello world
```